# Write a JQL query for an issue that has issue links of type defect and with the status open

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I need to write a JQL query that is looking for issues in a specific project with issue links of type resolves. Here is my JQL query: `project = NATMF and issuetype = Fix and issuelinktype = resolves`, I would like to refine this query to make sure that the issue links are of type Defect and that the status of the defect issue type is open. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter for the linked issues named "**Your_Linked_Filter_Name**" : `issuetype = Defect and status = open`. And in your JQL Query you should add `issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("Your_Linked_Filter_Name")`.

So your JQL Query should be like that : **`project = NATMF and issuetype = Fix and issuelinktype = resolves and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("Your_Linked_Filter_Name")`**

**NB :**
You should have the **ScriptRunner** plugin to use **issueFunction**.